# JavaScript doesn't load when app launched for the first time

Tags: javascript, ios, ios6, cordova, ios7

I'm working on a hybrid app, which uses iOS as native and Cordova-Phonegap to suppport html.

The JavaScript doesn't load when application is launched for the first time. We are able to get a call to `onDeviceReady` in Cordova Plugin class. From that class we are calling `webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method to call one of the JavaScript method.

That particular method is written in one file which has been added as link reference in HTML head section. But that method is not getting called on first launch. If I have already launched application and try to call the same method again using some other function that it is getting called successfully.

The code is really quiet simple, a HTML page with some JavaScript file reference and in JavaScript files we are have few purely JavaScript and jQuery functions.

We are loading our HTML page using **CDVViewController** as an `addSubview` to self.view

Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: what part of code doesn't work? show us some code

Comment: The html section doesn't load at all, on Page load event the javaScripts aren't loaded and a blank page is seen

Comment: just a lucky guess: when I instantiate a view controller, after creating/instantiating it, I call [viewcontroller layoutSubviews] to solve the first time run issues.

Comment: Added few more details. @CalinChitu: We have tried to call that in viewWillAppear but not solving our problem. :(

Comment: try to call ["CDVViewController viewcontroller name" layoutSubviews] somewhere just before addSubview.

Answer (score 2):

Well we finally figured out what the problem was. Some variables were not getting set in the first call and hence the page did not show up. Thanks for your help, anyways.